# Where do I see the payments from users (using Apple Pay as payment gateway in my app)

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect, applepay

I'm developing an App that uses apple pay as a payment method so that users can buy real life items (not in-app purchases); everything is already set up and works. The problem is, I don't really know where or when I'm supposed to receive those payments from the users. I already set up my banking info in appstore connect, but apart from that I don't know anything about this process and can't find info for such an important part of the feature. If anyone knows something about this, I would really appreciate your help.
[Image showing my agreements in appstore connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCvno.png)

Comment: For non-in-app purchases, the money would not be passed to App Store Connect. Are you sure you have set up the payment correctly according to [Processing the Payment Token](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/planning/)? For easier setup, consider using a [Payment Service Provider](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/payment-platforms/)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know that Apple didn't process Apple Pay payments. Looks like I'll have to find a payment processor here in my country (Costa Rica), which won't be easy task. Is it possible to develop my own solution to receive and decrypt the Apple Pay payment tokens and connect it to my bank account?

Comment: You might be able to follow [Apple Pay Web Merchant Registration API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applepaywebmerchantregistrationapi/registering_with_apple_pay_and_applying_to_use_the_api) to integrate your own solution, however I don't know too much about it. On the other hand, on the page that listed all the PSP, there's also a list of E-commerce platform that work with Apple Pay. There might be some that works for you region. However, they tend to charge a lot more fee that using a PSP.